# Can't understand the dot notations used in the pasted code written in Python

Tags: python, web-crawler

Recently, going through the code of a Python crawler I got stuck at some point not being able to understand the dot notation used to call the LINKS from the app class by PPN and CURRENT_APP [Both are marked and indicated with equal to symbol followed by (This One) marker to indicate which lines I meant]. My question is how come PPN and CURRENT_APP call the LINKS with dot notation?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

class app_crawler:
    def __init__(self,starturl,depth):
        self.starturl=starturl
        self.depth=depth
        self.current_depth=0
        self.depth_links=[]
        self.apps=[]
    def crawler(self):
        ppn=self.get_app(self.starturl)
        self.apps.append(ppn)
        self.depth_links.append(ppn.links)=======================================[This One]
        while self.current_depth < self.depth:
            current_links=[]
            for link in self.depth_links[self.current_depth]:
                current_app=self.get_app(link)
                current_links.extend(current_app.links)===================[This One]
                self.apps.append(current_app)
                self.current_depth+=1
                self.depth_links.append(current_links)


    def get_app(self,link):
        page = requests.get(link)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        name = tree.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()')[0]
        developper=tree.xpath('//div[@class="left"]/h2/text()')[0]
        price=tree.xpath('//div[@itemprop="price"]/text()')[0]
        links=tree.xpath('//div[@class="lockup-info"]//*/a[@class="name"]/@href')
        app=App(name, developper, price, links)
        return app


class App:
    def __init__(self,name,developper,price,links):
        self.name=name
        self.developper=developper
        self.price=price
        self.links=links========================================================[This One]

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Name: "+self.name +"\nDevelopper: "+self.developper+"\nPrice: "+self.price+"\n")

crawl=app_crawler("https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8",1)
crawl.crawler()
for data in crawl.apps:
    print(data)
```

Comment: Why do you understand `self.depth_links` but not `ppn.links`? What is the difference?

Comment: Perhaps your answer was sufficient enough to make someone understand the logic but I'm a newbie on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Links is a member of ppn, current_app, it can be accessed from them. 
Here ppn and current_app are created from get_app method, see that links is creted inside the method and is passed to App constructer.

links=tree.xpath('//div[@class="lockup-info"]//*/a[@class="name"]/@href')
app=App(name, developper, price, links)

Comment: Thanks for the clarity of your answer.